# Quickblox one-way streaming instead of 2-way video chat

Tags: quickblox

According to Quickblox support staff one-way streaming( one user streams ans other user can see it full screen, like on Periscope but it is one-to-one not one-to-many) is now possible with iOS SDK( They are also working to support it on Android and Web)but there is no any example for it. Right now i am facing multiple issues with this implementation:

In CallViewController.m, the video is being displayed via UICollectionViewCell. In that, I am getting the array self.users. When I initiate chat, I get 2 objects of the arrray. To have full screen view, I tried displaying one object on one device & second object on second device, but that breaks the video functionality and it doesn't work on any device. Quickblox is combining the video send & video received in an array. For having a one sided view, I need to alter this functionality.

Any example/guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is no such feature yet. It will be added in the near future, however no any ETA's yet.

Comment: Are you from Quickblox? If yes, then you should state that in your answers. Btw, according to Quickblox support it is supported . <<<Yes you can, this feature is currently available on iOS platform. We are currently working on the Web and Android platform.

Kind regards,
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Service Delivery & Project Manager 
QuickBlox